log/slog customising default handler

I want to use log/slog package default handler output format
Want to modify log message via custom Handle function: via custom Handle function or in some other way
Want to set custom handler as default

This code throws fatal error: all goroutines are asleep
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log/slog"
)

type CustomHandler struct {
    slog.Handler
}

func NewCustomHandler() CustomHandler {
    return CustomHandler{
        // 1. Want to use log/slog package default handler output format
        Handler: slog.Default().Handler(),
    }
}

func (m CustomHandler) Handle(ctx context.Context, record slog.Record) error {
    // 2. Want to modify log message via custom Handle function
    record.Message = "[do something] " + record.Message
    return m.Handler.Handle(ctx, record)
}

func main() {
    l := slog.New(NewCustomHandler())

    // 3. Want to set custom handler as default
    slog.SetDefault(l)

    slog.Info("Hello") // <- This throws fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
}

The comments inside SetDefault says:

If the default's handler is a defaultHandler, then don't use a handleWriter, or we'll deadlock as they both try to acquire the log default mutex. The defaultHandler will use whatever the log default writer is currently set to, which is correct. This can occur with SetDefault(Default()).

Question: Is there any other easy way to fulfill requirements 1, 2 and 3?
